# Map over SBT's Setting while keeping scopes?

Tags: scala, sbt

In a plugin, I've got a `SettingKey`, say:

```
val age = settingKey[Int]("An age")
```

Users can define this `age` in different scopes in their `build.sbt`'s:

```
age in Somewhere := 13

age in Whatever := 55
```

Now, in the plugin, I'd like to map all their definitions like so:

```
someOtherKey in ___ := if ((age in ___).value <= 10) "young" else "old"
```

... for each scope `___` that the `age` is defined in by the user.

Now, I don't know the scopes beforehand!

I think this used to be done with `mapReferenced` but it got deprecated in `0.13.2`. What's the proper way now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use derived settings, which are an advanced and undocumented API.  The idea is that if underlying keys exist, then your setting will automatically be pushed into a given configuration.  We use it for things like testOptions internally, but it hasn't been fully fleshed out in 0.13 series.   Here's an example:

```
inScope(Global)(Seq(
   Def.derive(someOtherKey := if(age.value <= 10) "young" else "old")
}
```

You can also set up derivation filters, such that e.g. you can only derive the setting into a project scope:

```
inScope(Global)(Seq(
   Def.derive(someOtherKey := if(age.value <= 10) "young" else "old", filter = _.project.isSelect)
}
```

Feel free to tamper around with the API.  As I stated, it's experimental and we're still working out the kinks.